# Overcoming Late Binding when passing it as a parameter

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I am using lambda to allow me use the full values within a range and in this case to create a series of buttons whose text variable is the same as their respective value in the range. I then want to create if/then statements that are particular to the value of x at that iteration but the problem arise as x when passed as a parameter unto the function goes right back to being treated as the last value in the range i.e the problem of late binding returns.

```
State_Full = ACTIVE
State_Null = DISABLED
Normal = NORMAL

i= 1
x=1

for x in range(1,6):
   Address_Hex = hex(x).lstrip("0x")
      btn = tk.Button(, height=1, width=10, relief=tk.RAISED, 
      disabledforeground` = "Red",state =State_Full,text= Address_Hex 
      ,command=lambda i=i,x=x: Write_Hex(x))

  btn.pack(padx=10, pady=2, side=tk.TOP)

  btn_1 = tk.Button(scframe.interior, height=1, width=10, relief=tk.RAISED,
                 text= "Opcode_1",disabledforeground = "Red", fg = "Blue" 
                 ,command=lambda i=i,x=x: Write_Opcode_1())
  btn_1.pack(padx=10, pady=2, side=tk.TOP)

  def Write_Hex(x):
      Address_Hex = hex(x).lstrip("0x")
      T.insert(tk.END, Address_Hex)
      State_1 = btn_1.cget("state")
      if  x <= 1 :
         btn_1['state'] = State_Null
      if x == 2:
         btn['state'] = State_Null
#^^^^^^The problem is above here, when x is 1 or 2 all of the buttons should 
turn off but only button 5 the end of the range turns off/disables^^^^^^
```

I expect that all buttons created by the range to become disabled and turn red but in this only 5 becomes disabled.

Comment: You should first fix your indentation.

Comment: ***"but in this only 5 becomes disabled."***: This is correct, as you use `btn[...` which references the **last** `Button` after the `for ...`. Read about [tkinter-events-and-bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) and use `binding` instead of `callback=`.

Comment: Could you expand upon that? I've been dabbling with binding and i read the page but i still do not see how binding solves the problem of Late Binding. I want to implement logical statements such as if and else at the states x=1, x=2 etc.

Comment: I've figured out that I can access x value within the scope of range but I haven't figured how to cause effects outside of this scope. The code follows if x == 1 then all following code will execute on the at ×=1 bit at this moment I cannot cause code from x=1 to affect x=2 attributes such as disabled or active